# Rails passing object to class in modules directory paypal-sdk-merchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am following the guide at http://www.tommyblue.it/2013/07/03/paypal-express-checkout-with-ruby-on-rails-and-paypal-sdk-merchant ;and, when I try to pass the order to the paypal_interface, I get a nil object.

```
def show
   @order = Order.find(params[:id]) 
   @paypal = PaypalInterface.new(@order) 
   @paypal.express_checkout 
   if @paypal.express_checkout_response.success?
   @paypal_url = @paypal.api.express_checkout_url(@paypal.express_checkout_response)
  else
   # manage error
  end
end
```

## edit to include entire file

paypal_interface.rb

```
require 'paypal-sdk-merchant'

class PaypalInterface
  attr_reader :api, :express_checkout_response

  PAYPAL_RETURN_URL = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.paid_orders_url(host: HOST_WO_HTTP)
  PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.revoked_orders_url(host: HOST_WO_HTTP)
  PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.ipn_orders_url(host: HOST_WO_HTTP)

 def initialize(order)
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
    @order = order
end

  @set_express_checkout = @api.build_set_express_checkout({
      SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails: {
        ReturnURL: PAYPAL_RETURN_URL,
        CancelURL: PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL,
       PaymentDetails: [{
          NotifyURL: PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL,
          OrderTotal: {
            currencyID: "EUR",
           value: @order.total
          },
          ItemTotal: {
            currencyID: "EUR",
           value: @order.total
          },
          ShippingTotal: {
           currencyID: "EUR",
           value: "0"
         },
         TaxTotal: {
           currencyID: "EUR",
           value: "0"
         },
          PaymentDetailsItem: [{
            Name: @order.code,
            Quantity: 1,
            Amount: {
             currencyID: "EUR",
              value: @order.total
            },
            ItemCategory: "Physical"
          }],
          PaymentAction: "Sale"
        }]
      }
        })
# Make API call & get response
    @express_checkout_response = @api.set_express_checkout(@set_express_checkout)

    # Access Response
    if @express_checkout_response.success?
      @order.set_payment_token(@express_checkout_response.Token)
    else
      @express_checkout_response.Errors
    end


def do_express_checkout
    @do_express_checkout_payment = @api.build_do_express_checkout_payment({
      DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails: {
        PaymentAction: "Sale",
        Token: @order.payment_token,
        PayerID: @order.payerID,
        PaymentDetails: [{
          OrderTotal: {
            currencyID: "EUR",
            value: @order.total
          },
          NotifyURL: PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL
        }]
      }
    })

    # Make API call & get response
    @do_express_checkout_payment_response = @api.do_express_checkout_payment(@do_express_checkout_payment)

    # Access Response
    if @do_express_checkout_payment_response.success?
      details = @do_express_checkout_payment_response.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails
     @order.set_payment_details(prepare_express_checkout_response(details))
    else
      errors = @do_express_checkout_payment_response.Errors # => Array
      @order.save_payment_errors errors
    end
  end
    end
```

The class is in /lib/modules and when loaded, the instance variables are nil

Started GET "/orders/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-07 01:33:46 -0600
Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/modules/paypal_interface.rb:25:in`'
  lib/modules/paypal_interface.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:17:in`show'

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140107060318) do

  create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|
   t.text     "code"
   t.text     "total"
   t.text     "payerID"
   t.text     "payment_token"
   t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

end
```

I loaded a value of 10 into the form;and, i tried changing the total field to :decimal to no avail, but now I am stuck as the object does not pass to the module from the order controller.

Answer (score 1):

If **@question** in **PaypalInterface** is nil, probably `Order.find(params[:id])` doesn't find any.
In the show method:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
```

**@order** is nil?
You could try with:

```
def show
   if @order = Order.find(params[:id])
     [...]
   else
     # Can't find order
   end
end
```

I use Pry to debug this kind of errors, just require 'pry' then put **binding.pry** where you want to stop the code and open a console. An example is:

```
def show
   @order = Order.find(params[:id])
   require 'pry'
   binding.pry # Go to the console and start debugging @order
   [...]
end
```

ps. What you indicate as **paypal_interface.rb** is only a part of that file? Because that code seems wrong.

Comment: yeah, it is finding the order in the show method. I edited paypal_interface.rb to include the entire file.  I am checking out pry now. thanks

Comment: [24] pry(main)> cd PaypalInterface
Error: Bad object path: PaypalInterface. Failed trying to resolve: PaypalInterface. #<NoMethodError: undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass>

Comment: edited paypal_interface.rb again-modified end statements- still no object passed

Comment: Are you loading the file? To do it put in `config/application.rb`:

```config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)```

Comment: Yes, but like this.  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]